# where are the spamassassin KHOP rules?

Tags: email

I have this spamassassin implementation where I lowered the score on:

**KHOP_BIG_TO_CC**

It works when I override the score in my /etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf file but I cannot find the .cf file that holds this specific rule.

Checked both the locations where rules are kept:

- /usr/share/spamassassin
- /etc/mail/spamassassin

And also some local users home folder like

- /root/.spamassassin/
- /var/amavisd/.spamassassin/

Did a grep on the directories like this:

```
grep -r "KHOP_BIG_TO_CC" /<directory/path/*
```

but nothing, I find other KHOP rules but never this one although it shows up in the xspam headers.

Now I have read somewhere that there exists an khop channel:
http://khopesh.com/wiki/Anti-spam

however, the only channel I read with sa-update is "sought.rules.yerp.org"

Does anyobody recognize the **KHOP_BIG_TO_CC** rule and knows where i can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer about KHOP_BIG_TO_CC, but here's some tips for exploring your server:

You can view which rule files are being loaded by spamassassin with this command:

```
spamassassin --lint -D 2>&1 | grep 'config: read file'
```

On a RHEL 6 system using `sa-update` I found the rule sets under `/var/lib/spamassassin`. You can grep all cf files with:

```
grep KHOP_BIG_TO_CC $(spamassassin --lint -D 2>&1 | grep 'config: read file' | sed 's/^.* read file //')
```

On my system no `KHOP_` rules were found.

Not likely, but perhaps it is possible, depending on how your system is setup, for individual users to define their own spamassassin rules, in which case they might be under something like `$HOME/.spamassassin/user_prefs`? In this case the `--lint -D` command above wouldn't display all parsed user rules.

But regardless of where `KHOP_BIG_TO_CC` is defined, you can override the score used by it by adding the following to your `local.cf` file:

```
score KHOP_BIG_TO_CC 0.0
```

You wouldn't be editing core rule files anyways, so it doesn't really matter where they are found (although I can understand the frustration of not being able to find the file where it is defined).